# How does the >> operator works when we have a number and string

Tags: c++

I know that when working with strings, from the definition the >> operator means
`Extract string from stream` and we normally use it to store it on a variable doing something like this:
`std::cin >> name;`
With numbers it is a Bitwise right shift operator, still it seems a bit comfusing to me, why does it have 2 meanings?

I've seen examples like this:

```
        crc = crc16xmodem_table[((crc >> 12) ^ (*data >> 4)) & 0x0F] ^ (crc << 4);
```

looking at that we see `crc >> 12`, `data >> 4`.

How does this really work differently with numbers and strings? 
Does it have something to do how strings and ints are implemented?

Comment: It's also a bit shift operator. It has multiple meanings.

Comment: In the code shown, `crc` and `*data` are numeric variables, not streams, so `>>` is the BITWISE RIGHT SHIFT operator and `<<` is the BITWISE LEFT SHIFT operator. They are not the STREAM EXTRACTION and STREAM INSERTION operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it in simple mathematical terms:

`x<<y == x*2^y`

`x>>y == x/2^y` (integer division)

For example, 3 in binary is `11b`. `3>>1==1` because `3/2==1`, and `1==1b`.
Another example:

`21==10101b`

`21>>2==5`

`10101b>>10b==101b`

`21==10101b`

`21<<2==84`

`10101b<<10b==1010100b`